inputting ordered values from a list of dataframe with different row numbers into a list of dataframe with equal row numbers
I am stuck with this problem. Please note that I have edited the original question because I have forgotten to provide crucial details for solving this problem.
My sincere apologies for this mistake go to the first kind responser of this question!
The MWE is provided below
mydf.1 <- data.frame(age=factor(c(0:4,6:10),levels=c(0:4,6:10),ordered=TRUE), Freq=c(1,2,3,7,8,9,10,5,10,10))
mydf.2 <- data.frame(age=factor(6:10,levels=c(6:10),ordered=TRUE),Freq=c(10,5,10,10,21))
mydf.3 <- data.frame(age=factor(0:3,levels=c(0:3),ordered=TRUE),Freq=c(1,5,9,4))
mydf.list <- list(mydf.1,mydf.2,mydf.3)
mydf.list

#desired output
myout.1 <- data.frame(age=factor(0:10,levels=c(0:10),ordered=TRUE), Freq=c(1,2,3,7,8,0,9,10,5,10,10))
myout.2 <- data.frame(age=factor(0:10,levels=c(0:10),ordered=TRUE),Freq=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,10,5,10,10,21))
myout.3 <- data.frame(age=factor(0:10,levels=c(0:10),ordered=TRUE),Freq=c(1,5,9,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
myout.list <- list(myout.1,myout.2,myout.3)
myout.list

#My best unsuccessful attempt
mydf.empty <- data.frame(age=factor(0:10,levels=c(0:10),ordered=TRUE),Freq=c(rep(0,11)))
myrows <- list()
for (i in c(1:3)){
myrows[[i]] <- rownames(mydf.empty)[rownames(mydf.empty) %in% rownames(mydf.list[[i]])]
}
myrows

Any helps would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Stef

You have set rownames with various start values for mymatrix.list items, but matrices in  desired output  are without rownames , all shaped as 5x1 and are just filled from top-left.  So.. should  rownames play any role here? Or would you expect a list of 11x1 matrices as a result?

You were right, because I imagine that the solution to this problem likely involves either rownames and colnames too. I am very sorry for this confusion!

Perhaps consider rolling back to the previous version and open a new question? Regarding datasets in your update, is there a valid reason to have factors at this stage or it doesn't actually matter and you could (re-)create those once all frames in the list are expanded?

Following only targets 2nd revision (list of frames with a factor column), which is quite different from the original question (list of matrices)

You could first unify the levels of list of factors with forcats::fct_unify() , once original age values are replaced with unified variants, tidyr::complete() can turn implicit missing values into explicit missing values, i.e. complete a frame with all age levels.
purrr::map() is used to extract a column from a list of frames, returns a list of age factors.
purrr::map2() is used to iterate over pairs of items in mydf.list & list of age.
purrr::map2(
  mydf.list, 
  purrr::map(mydf.list, "age") |> forcats::fct_unify(),
  \(df, age_unif_lvl)  dplyr::mutate(df, age = age_unif_lvl) |> tidyr::complete(age, fill = list(Freq = 0))
)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>    age    Freq
#>    <ord> <dbl>
#>  1 0         1
#>  2 1         2
#>  3 2         3
#>  4 3         7
#>  5 4         8
#>  6 6         9
#>  7 7        10
#>  8 8         5
#>  9 9        10
#> 10 10       10
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>    age    Freq
#>    <ord> <dbl>
#>  1 0         0
#>  2 1         0
#>  3 2         0
#>  4 3         0
#>  5 4         0
#>  6 6        10
#>  7 7         5
#>  8 8        10
#>  9 9        10
#> 10 10       21
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>    age    Freq
#>    <ord> <dbl>
#>  1 0         1
#>  2 1         5
#>  3 2         9
#>  4 3         4
#>  5 4         0
#>  6 6         0
#>  7 7         0
#>  8 8         0
#>  9 9         0
#> 10 10        0

Example data:
mydf.1 <- data.frame(age=factor(c(0:4,6:10),levels=c(0:4,6:10),ordered=TRUE), Freq=c(1,2,3,7,8,9,10,5,10,10))
mydf.2 <- data.frame(age=factor(6:10,levels=c(6:10),ordered=TRUE),Freq=c(10,5,10,10,21))
mydf.3 <- data.frame(age=factor(0:3,levels=c(0:3),ordered=TRUE),Freq=c(1,5,9,4))
mydf.list <- list(mydf.1,mydf.2,mydf.3)
str(mydf.list)
#> List of 3
#>  $ :'data.frame':    10 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ age : Ord.factor w/ 10 levels "0"<"1"<"2"<"3"<..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#>   ..$ Freq: num [1:10] 1 2 3 7 8 9 10 5 10 10
#>  $ :'data.frame':    5 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ age : Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "6"<"7"<"8"<"9"<..: 1 2 3 4 5
#>   ..$ Freq: num [1:5] 10 5 10 10 21
#>  $ :'data.frame':    4 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ age : Ord.factor w/ 4 levels "0"<"1"<"2"<"3": 1 2 3 4
#>   ..$ Freq: num [1:4] 1 5 9 4

#desired output
myout.1 <- data.frame(age=factor(0:10,levels=c(0:10),ordered=TRUE), Freq=c(1,2,3,7,8,0,9,10,5,10,10))
myout.2 <- data.frame(age=factor(0:10,levels=c(0:10),ordered=TRUE),Freq=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,10,5,10,10,21))
myout.3 <- data.frame(age=factor(0:10,levels=c(0:10),ordered=TRUE),Freq=c(1,5,9,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
myout.list <- list(myout.1,myout.2,myout.3)
str(myout.list)
#> List of 3
#>  $ :'data.frame':    11 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ age : Ord.factor w/ 11 levels "0"<"1"<"2"<"3"<..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>   ..$ Freq: num [1:11] 1 2 3 7 8 0 9 10 5 10 ...
#>  $ :'data.frame':    11 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ age : Ord.factor w/ 11 levels "0"<"1"<"2"<"3"<..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>   ..$ Freq: num [1:11] 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 5 10 10 ...
#>  $ :'data.frame':    11 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ age : Ord.factor w/ 11 levels "0"<"1"<"2"<"3"<..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>   ..$ Freq: num [1:11] 1 5 9 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...


Created on 2024-10-22 with reprex v2.1.1

thank you @margusl! I have marked your solution as the best one.

We assume that the problem is to input a list of single column matrices and output it zero filled at the end to the length of the longest.  Dimnames should be dropped.
We calculate the lengths lens and a template template.  Then we update the
template using replace for each input list element.
lens <- lengths(mymatrix.list)
template <- matrix(0, max(lens), 1)

Replace <- function(m, len) replace(template, seq_along(m), m)
out <- Map(Replace, mymatrix.list, lens)

identical(out, myoutput.list)
## [1] TRUE

If the number of columns is not necessarily 1 then use this more general formulation:
dims <- lapply(mymatrix.list, dim)
template <- array(0, Reduce(pmax, dims))

Replace <- function(m) {
  template[seq_len(nrow(m)), seq_len(ncol(m))] <- m
  template
}

out <- Map(Replace, mymatrix.list)

identical(out, myoutput.list)
## [1] TRUE

Note
mymatrix.list <- list(
  matrix(c(1, 2, 3), 3, dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3"), NULL)),
  matrix(seq(4, 7, by = 1), 4, dimnames = list(c("4", "5", "6", "7"), NULL)),
  matrix(seq(7, 11, by = 1), 5, dimnames = list(c("7", "8", "9", "10", "11"), NULL))
)

myoutput.list <- list(
  matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 0, 0), 5),
  matrix(c(4, 5, 6, 7, 0), 5),
  matrix(seq(7, 11, by = 1), 5)
)


Thank you very much @G. Grothendieck!!! Also for providing the more general solution when dealing with more columns.

I am very sorry G. Grothendieck for this  confusion. I have forgotten to provide some crucial details for solving this problem. My sincere apologies to you.

Eventually, I got it but my solution requires more lines of code.
Thank you very much to anyone who has provided a solution and I apologies again for the confusion between the first post and the definitive one.
Stef
myrows.in <- list()
myrows.out <- list()

for (i in c(1:3)){
myrows.in[[i]] <- match(mydf.empty$age,mydf.list[[i]]$age)
myrows.out[[i]] <- match(mydf.list[[i]]$age,mydf.empty$age)
}
myrows.in
myrows.out

#creating an empty list of dataframe
mydf.empty <- 
data.frame(age=factor(0:14,levels=c(0:14),ordered=TRUE),Freq=c(rep(0,15)))
mydf.out.list <- list()
for (i in c(1:3)){
mydf.out.list[[i]] <- mydf.empty
}
mydf.out.list

#filling the empty list of dataframe
for (i in c(1:3)){
mydf.out.list[[i]]$Freq[unlist(myrows.out[i])] <- 
mydf.list[[i]]$Freq[na.omit(unlist(myrows.in[i]))] 
}
mydf.out.list
identical(myout.list[1],mydf.out.list[1])
identical(myout.list[2],mydf.out.list[2])
identical(myout.list[3],mydf.out.list[3])

